# How do I get the strides from a dtype in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, stride

I think I can do: `np.zeros((), dtype=dt).strides`, but this doesn't seem efficient when the dtype is a large array type like: `('<f8', (200, 100))`.  Is there a way of going directly from dtype to strides in numpy?

Comment: The strides aren't a property of the `dtype`, they're a property of the array.  `x.strides` depends on `x.shape`.  Furthermore, the strides reflect the ordering of the array in memory (e.g. C vs Fortran order or things like `x = x[::2]`).  Therefore strides are specific to a specific memory layout of a specific array of a specific shape.

Comment: @JoeKington: See my example.  The dtype can have a shape within it and that's what I'm trying to get strides from.  The memory order is also specified in the dtype ("<").

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now! I missed that part. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I think fields of a dtype with a shape within a structured array are required to be in C-order, but I'm not 100% sure on that.  At any rate, the `<` specifies little-endian, not memory order.

Comment: @JoeKington: Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually get the strides of a sub-array within a structured array without creating the "full" array.

Sub-arrays within a structured array are required to be contiguous and in C-order [according to the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Note the sentence just above the first example:

> Sub-arrays always have a C-contiguous memory layout.

Therefore, for a structured array with no fields such as the one in your example, you can do (as an unreadable one-liner):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.dtype(('<f8', (200, 100)))

strides = x.base.itemsize * np.r_[1, np.cumprod(x.shape[::-1][:-1])][::-1]
```

Avoiding the code golf:

```
shape = list(x.shape)

# First, let's make the strides for an array with an itemsize of 1 in C-order
tmp_strides = shape[::-1]
tmp_strides[1:] = list(np.cumprod(tmp_strides[:-1]))
tmp_strides[0] = 1

# Now adjust it for the real itemsize:
tmp_strides = x.base.itemsize * np.array(tmp_strides)

# And convert it to a tuple, reversing it back for proper C-order
strides = tuple(tmp_strides[::-1])
```

This gets more complex when there are multiple fields, however. You'd need to put in approriate checks in general.  For example: Does the dtype have a `shape` attribute? Does it have fields? Do any fields have `shape` attributes?

Comment: I had it using the itemsize in my old code.  Is it guaranteed to store the elements of the array contiguously?

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, the elements of the subarray are guarenteed to be contiguous and in C-order.  (Also I have a mistake in the long version of the code in my answer. Fixing now. The one-liner is correct, though.)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the broken link initially: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html  Have a look at the sentence above the first example.

Comment: Aha!  Yes you're right.  I used to do this in my old code, but then I wanted to use strides to be super safe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about an array with:

```
In [257]: dt=np.dtype([('f0',float, (200,100))])
In [258]: x=np.zeros((),dtype=dt)
```

The array itself is 0d with one item.

```
In [259]: x.strides
Out[259]: ()
```

That item has shape and strides determined by the dtype:

```
In [260]: x['f0'].strides
Out[260]: (800, 8)
In [261]: x['f0'].shape
Out[261]: (200, 100)
```

But is constructing `x` any different than constructing a plain float array with the same shape?

```
In [262]: y=np.zeros((200,100),float)
In [263]: y.strides
Out[263]: (800, 8)
```

You can't get the strides of a potential `y` without actually constructing it.

Ipython whos command shows `x` and `y` take up about the same space:

```
x          ndarray       : 1 elems, type `[('f0', '<f8', (200, 100))]`,
   160000 bytes (156.25 kb)
y          ndarray       200x100: 20000 elems, type `float64`, 
   160000 bytes (156.25 kb)
```

An iteresting question is whether such an `x['f0']` has all the properties of `y`.  You can probably read all the properties, but may be limited in what ones you can change.

---

You can parse the dtype:

```
In [309]: dt=np.dtype([('f0',float, (200,100))])
In [310]: dt.fields
Out[310]: mappingproxy({'f0': (dtype(('<f8', (200, 100))), 0)})
In [311]: dt[0]
Out[311]: dtype(('<f8', (200, 100)))
In [312]: dt[0].shape
Out[312]: (200, 100)
In [324]: dt[0].base
Out[324]: dtype('float64')
```

I don't see a `strides` like attribute of `dt` or `dt[0]`.  There may be some `numpy` function that calculates the `strides`, based on `shape`, but it probably is hidden.  You could search the `np.lib.stride_tricks` module.  That's where `as_strided` is found.

From the `(200,100)` shape, and `float64` taking 8 bytes, it is possible calculate that the normal (default) strides is `(8*100, 8)`.

For dtype that isn't further nested, this seems to work:

```
In [374]: dt[0]
Out[374]: dtype(('<f8', (200, 100)))
In [375]: tuple(np.array(dt[0].shape[1:]+(1,))*dt[0].base.itemsize)
Out[375]: (800, 8)
```

---

Lets make a more complex array with this dtype

```
In [346]: x=np.zeros((3,1),dtype=dt)
In [347]: x.shape
Out[347]: (3, 1)
In [348]: x.strides
Out[348]: (160000, 160000)
```

Its strides depends on the shape and `itemsize`.  But the shape and strides of a field are 4d.  Can we say they exist without actually accessing the field?

```
In [349]: x['f0'].strides
Out[349]: (160000, 160000, 800, 8)
```

strides for an item:

```
In [350]: x[0,0]['f0'].strides
Out[350]: (800, 8)
```

---

How about double nesting?

```
In [390]: dt1=np.dtype([('f0',np.dtype([('f00',int,(3,4))]), (20,10))])
In [391]: z=np.zeros((),dt1)
In [392]: z['f0']['f00'].shape
Out[392]: (20, 10, 3, 4)
In [393]: z['f0']['f00'].strides
Out[393]: (480, 48, 16, 4)
In [399]: (np.cumprod(np.array((10,3,4,1))[::-1])*4)[::-1]
Out[399]: array([480,  48,  16,   4], dtype=int32)
```

---

correction, the striding for a field is a combination of the striding for the array as a whole plus striding for the field.  It can be seen with a multifield dtype

```
In [430]: dt=np.dtype([('f0',float, (3,4)),('f1',int),('f2',int,(2,))])
In [431]: x=np.zeros((3,2),dt)
In [432]: x.shape
Out[432]: (3, 2)
In [433]: x.strides
Out[433]: (216, 108)
In [434]: x['f0'].shape
Out[434]: (3, 2, 3, 4)
In [435]: x['f0'].strides
Out[435]: (216, 108, 32, 8)
```

`(216,108)` is striding for the whole array (itemsize is 108), concatenated with the striding for the `f0` field `(32,8)` (itemsize 8).

Comment: That's my point: You should be able to get the strides without reconstructing the array.  Also, to answer your question, the reason I have a dtype with a shape is that it exists as part of a more complicated dtype whose corresponding array will have an additional shape when it is created (later).

Comment: Regarding your edit: I know about fields and reading the sub-dtype shapes.  What I want are the strides.

Comment: I can calculate strides from a shape and base dtype, assuming normal construction.  But I have to have an actual array to find a strides attribute.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't realize that the array was stored contiguously and it was just a matter of calculation.